# Como convierto una url BLOB:xxxxxxxxxx que utilizo en una vista previa de imagen un un BLOB o FILE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, mvc

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que quiero subir imágenes a un servidor, pero antes de enviarlo al servidor, se muestra una vista previa de la imagen, para eso uso el siguiente código. Cabe mencionar que el usuario puede elegir varias imágenes y en varias ocasiones que se van agregando a un div como vista previa.

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input:file', function (e) {
                   
                    //document.getElementById('listimangen').addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", Reaubicar, false);
                    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {

                        var image_object_url = URL.createObjectURL($(this).get(0).files[i]);
                        $('#container').append($('<div class="thumbnail"/>').load("/Proyectos/ImagenBrief?url=" + image_object_url, function () {}));
                    }              
                });
```

Dentro del evento `Change` genero la URL de tipo BLOB para mostrar la vista previa sin subir imagen al servidor.

Mi problema es como envió el src de la vista previa a guardar al servidor si es una url blob